# PHP password email taken and password confirm form error message print

Tags: php

I have an issue when it comes to email being used twice. It does not print to notify the user that he already has that email used. I had it working before however after adding password confirmation field it stop working. What I want it to do is print "Email is invalid or already taken." when the email is registered again.

```html
if ($count==0) {
   if ($_POST["password"] == $_POST["confirm_password"]) {
      $query = "INSERT INTO login(username,email,password) VALUES('$username','$email','$encrypt')";
      if ($dbConnect->query($query)) {
       $alert = "<div class='alert alert-success'>
          <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; Registered successfully!
         </div>";
      }else {
       $alert = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
          <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; Error try again or contact web master!
         </div>";
      }

     } else {


      $alert = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
         <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; Email is invalid or already taken.</div>";

     }

   }
```

Comment: Sorry, but simply dumping your full script here and asking "why doesn't this work" is not considered a good question. Please start debugging yourself. This is _your_ script. We are only able to help with _specific_ questions if they arise.

Comment: i think u need to add else confition for `if ($count==0) {` not for `if ($_POST["password"] == $_POST["confirm_password"]) {`

Comment: The `else` branch is on the wrong level which you would see yourself when using proper indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You put email exists code block in `if($count == 0)` block. It shouldn't be there. It would be in else block. Use below code.

```
if ($count==0) 
{
   if ($_POST["password"] == $_POST["confirm_password"]) 
   {
      $query = "INSERT INTO login(username,email,password) VALUES('$username','$email','$encrypt')";

      if ($dbConnect->query($query)) 
      {
       $alert = "<div class='alert alert-success'>
          <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; Registered successfully!
         </div>";
      }
      else 
      {
       $alert = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
          <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; Error try again or contact web master!
         </div>";
      }

    } 
}
else 
{
  $alert = "<div class='alert alert-danger'>
     <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign'></span> &nbsp; Email is invalid or already taken.</div>";

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistants!